# Create materialized view much slower than create table

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I've got a query that I'd like to use to back a materialized view.

When I use this syntax to create a regular table from the view, it executes very quickly (5 seconds):

```
create table my_table as select * from my_view;
```

However, when I try to create the materialized view from the same view, it's MUCH slower (5+ minutes).

```
create materialized view my_materialized_view refresh complete start with sysdate next trunc(sysdate, 'HH') + (1/24)  AS select * from my_view;
```

I've already optimized the view query as much as possible.  Selecting directly from the view is quick, as well as creating any number of tables from the view.  It's only after I pass it through create materialized view.

Any ideas what could be causing the slowdown?  Anything I can do (hints, etc) to help it execute quicker when creating the materialize view?

Comment: Have you tried using a prebuilt table for the MV?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I don't have an answer.  I too have encountered this problem and could not explain it.  In my case I just implemented the MV as a table, and everyone was happy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference(and the problem) may be that the refresh does **delete** and insert. The create table does only select-insert. But refresh does delete-select-insert.

Try to do it with truncate. Don't know the sintax by heart, can be found in docs.

Comment: The OP says it's slow on create, not on refresh. Nice idea though, even if a factor of 60+ increase for a delete still sounds rather high. (And... you can't truncate an MV, can you?)

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right, the OP talks about create. I didn't noticed that. I googled for a second: if the mv is not in a refresh group, refresh will do a truncate.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that, but don't use MVs much. I thought you meant a straight truncate, like on a table.